# Rabbitmq start fails

Tags: rabbitmq

My RabbitMQ server went down and it is impossible to restart it. I tried to restart, reinstall it... I still don't understand the error.
This is what I get

```
BOOT FAILED

===========

Error description:
   {could_not_start,rabbit,
    {bad_return,
     {{rabbit,start,[normal,[]]},
      {'EXIT',
       {rabbit,failure_during_boot,
        {badmatch,
         {error,
          {{{function_clause,
             [{rabbit_queue_index,journal_minus_segment1,
               [{no_pub,del,no_ack},
                {{<<115,254,171,167,171,226,110,171,251,38,217,145,3,12,215,151>>,
                  {message_properties,1409712663123302,false},
                  true},
                 del,ack}],
               [{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,989}]},
              {rabbit_queue_index,'-journal_minus_segment/2-fun-0-',4,
               [{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,973}]},
              {array,sparse_foldl_3,7,[{file,"array.erl"},{line,1675}]},
              {array,sparse_foldl_2,9,[{file,"array.erl"},{line,1669}]},
              {rabbit_queue_index,'-recover_journal/1-fun-0-',1,
               [{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,701}]},
              {lists,map,2,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1224}]},
              {rabbit_queue_index,segment_map,2,
               [{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,819}]},
              {rabbit_queue_index,recover_journal,1,
               [{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,693}]}]},
            {gen_server2,call,[<0.186.0>,out,infinity]}},
           {child,undefined,msg_store_persistent,
            {rabbit_msg_store,start_link,
             [msg_store_persistent,
              "/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@host",[],
              {#Fun<rabbit_queue_index.2.132977059>,
               {start,
                [{resource,<<"/">>,queue,
                  <<"photos_to_be_tagged_user_36">>}]}}]},
            transient,4294967295,worker,
            [rabbit_msg_store]}}}}}}}}}
```

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: use sudo to start rabbitmq.

Comment: I already did. The logs are from the command sudo rabbitmq-server start

Comment: maybe the problem is mnesia DB, if you can erase your data, try to delete the mnesia DB here /var/lib/rabbitmq/. note : this WILL DELETE all your data stored to the queue.

Comment: Yes, I did move mnesia and it seems to work now. What was the error? Since I didn't do anything in particular and it has been running fine for the last weeks ...

Comment: Good question, I don't know exactly, could be an disk error for example. The data-base seems corrupted.

Comment: Thanks for your help! My whole system seems to be broken though ... This is really obscure, if anybody has an idea, I would appreciate very much an explanation.

Comment: Please refer my fix in, https://stackoverflow.com/a/62019910/4817250

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For anyone else looking for this error rabbit,failure_during_boot,

```
{badmatch,  
     {error,  
      {{{function_clause,  
         [{rabbit_queue_index,journal_minus_segment1, ...
```

I just dealt with the same issue and what helped was going to the mnesia directories and deleting the queues and msg_store_transient directories.

From what I understand, what happens is that you end up with a bad queue db (for whatever reason -i.e. a sudden power failure, some other process touches the files) which rabbitmq can't parse and so it crashes. Once you clear the queue of messages, it works fine.

Comment: Thanks. I was worried about doing that, but it recovered nicely. My affected instance is part of a cluster and it synced up with the other one nicely after deleting the queues and msg_store_persistent (in my case) directories.

Comment: Thanks, Man. You saved my day

Comment: Thanks, after deleting the files, the issue got resolved. And for more info, files will be located under /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@<USERNAME>/. Here mainly you need to clear the content from these directories msg_store_persistent, msg_store_transient, and queues.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same issue and this is what helped me.

The Mnesia files in questions were located in `/var/lib/rabbitmq/`.

Answer (score 1):

I had to delete everything in `...\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ\db`, not just the `Mnesia` files (on Windows, obviously).