# RabbitMQ virtual host error when starting service

Tags: rabbitmq

I've had a RabbitMQ server running for months. This morning I was unable to connect to it, my applications was timing out and the Management client was unresponsive. Rebooted the machine. Applications are still timing out. I'm able to login to the Management client but I see this message:

> Virtual host / experienced an error on node rabbit@MQT01 and may be inaccessible

All my queues are there but can't see any exchanges.

I hope someone can help me figure out what going on. I've looked at the logs but can't find any good hint.

Here a part of the log:

```html
2018-09-11 09:39:42 =ERROR REPORT====
** Generic server <0.281.0> terminating
** Last message in was {'$gen_cast',{submit_async,#Fun<rabbit_queue_index.36.122888644>}}
** When Server state == undefined
** Reason for termination == 
** {function_clause,[{rabbit_queue_index,journal_minus_segment1,[{{true,<<172,190,166,92,192,205,125,125,36,223,114,188,53,139,128,108,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,26,151>>,<<>>},no_del,no_ack},{{true,<<89,173,78,227,188,37,119,171,231,189,220,236,244,79,138,177,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,40>>,<<>>},no_del,no_ack}],[{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,1231}]},{rabbit_queue_index,'-journal_minus_segment/3-fun-0-',4,[{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,1208}]},{array,sparse_foldl_3,7,[{file,"array.erl"},{line,1684}]},{array,sparse_foldl_2,9,[{file,"array.erl"},{line,1678}]},{rabbit_queue_index,'-recover_journal/1-fun-0-',1,[{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,915}]},{lists,map,2,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1239}]},{rabbit_queue_index,segment_map,2,[{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,1039}]},{rabbit_queue_index,recover_journal,1,[{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,906}]}]}
2018-09-11 09:39:42 =CRASH REPORT====
  crasher:
    initial call: worker_pool_worker:init/1
    pid: <0.281.0>
    registered_name: []
    exception exit: {{function_clause,[{rabbit_queue_index,journal_minus_segment1,[{{true,<<172,190,166,92,192,205,125,125,36,223,114,188,53,139,128,108,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,26,151>>,<<>>},no_del,no_ack},{{true,<<89,173,78,227,188,37,119,171,231,189,220,236,244,79,138,177,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,40>>,<<>>},no_del,no_ack}],[{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,1231}]},{rabbit_queue_index,'-journal_minus_segment/3-fun-0-',4,[{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,1208}]},{array,sparse_foldl_3,7,[{file,"array.erl"},{line,1684}]},{array,sparse_foldl_2,9,[{file,"array.erl"},{line,1678}]},{rabbit_queue_index,'-recover_journal/1-fun-0-',1,[{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,915}]},{lists,map,2,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1239}]},{rabbit_queue_index,segment_map,2,[{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,1039}]},{rabbit_queue_index,recover_journal,1,[{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,906}]}]},[{gen_server2,terminate,3,[{file,"src/gen_server2.erl"},{line,1161}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,247}]}]}
    ancestors: [worker_pool_sup,rabbit_sup,<0.262.0>]
    message_queue_len: 0
    messages: []
    links: [<0.276.0>,<0.336.0>,#Port<0.31196>]
    dictionary: [{fhc_age_tree,{1,{{10352640,#Ref<0.1077581647.1695285251.67028>},true,nil,nil}}},{worker_pool_worker,true},{rand_seed,{#{jump => #Fun<rand.16.15449617>,max => 288230376151711743,next => #Fun<rand.15.15449617>,type => exsplus},[257570830250844431|246837015578235662]}},{worker_pool_name,worker_pool},{{"c:/Users/dfpsb/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/db/RABBIT~1/msg_stores/vhosts/628WB79CIFDYO9LJI6DKMI09L/queues/9GD33C2I2PKZ7A8QHZ4MWWCKE/journal.jif",fhc_file},{file,1,true}},{{#Ref<0.1077581647.1695285251.67028>,fhc_handle},{handle,{file_descriptor,prim_file,{#Port<0.31196>,1808}},#Ref<0.1077581647.1695285251.67028>,240,false,0,infinity,[],<<>>,0,0,0,0,0,false,"c:/Users/dfpsb/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/db/RABBIT~1/msg_stores/vhosts/628WB79CIFDYO9LJI6DKMI09L/queues/9GD33C2I2PKZ7A8QHZ4MWWCKE/journal.jif",[write,binary,raw,read],[{write_buffer,infinity}],true,true,10352640}}]
    trap_exit: false
    status: running
    heap_size: 10958
    stack_size: 27
    reductions: 104391
  neighbours:
    neighbour: [{pid,<0.279.0>},{registered_name,[]},{initial_call,{worker_pool_worker,init,['Argument__1']}},{current_function,{gen,do_call,4}},{ancestors,[worker_pool_sup,rabbit_sup,<0.262.0>]},{message_queue_len,0},{links,[<0.276.0>,<0.336.0>]},{trap_exit,false},{status,waiting},{heap_size,4185},{stack_size,42},{reductions,21548},{current_stacktrace,[{gen,do_call,4,[{file,"gen.erl"},{line,169}]},{gen_server,call,3,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,210}]},{file,call,2,[{file,"file.erl"},{line,1499}]},{rabbit_queue_index,get_journal_handle,1,[{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,881}]},{rabbit_queue_index,load_journal,1,[{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,894}]},{rabbit_queue_index,recover_journal,1,[{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,904}]},{rabbit_queue_index,scan_queue_segments,3,[{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,724}]},{rabbit_queue_index,queue_index_walker_reader,2,[{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,712}]}]}]
    neighbour: [{pid,<0.278.0>},{registered_name,[]},{initial_call,{worker_pool_worker,init,['Argument__1']}},{current_function,{gen,do_call,4}},{ancestors,[worker_pool_sup,rabbit_sup,<0.262.0>]},{message_queue_len,0},{links,[<0.276.0>,<0.336.0>,#Port<0.31157>]},{trap_exit,false},{status,waiting},{heap_size,6772},{stack_size,102},{reductions,129623},{current_stacktrace,[{gen,do_call,4,[{file,"gen.erl"},{line,169}]},{gen_server2,call,3,[{file,"src/gen_server2.erl"},{line,323}]},{array,sparse_foldr_3,6,[{file,"array.erl"},{line,1848}]},{array,sparse_foldr_2,8,[{file,"array.erl"},{line,1837}]},{lists,foldr,3,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1276}]},{rabbit_queue_index,scan_queue_segments,3,[{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,725}]},{rabbit_queue_index,queue_index_walker_reader,2,[{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,712}]},{rabbit_queue_index,'-queue_index_walker/1-fun-0-',2,[{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,694}]}]}]
    neighbour: [{pid,<0.280.0>},{registered_name,[]},{initial_call,{worker_pool_worker,init,['Argument__1']}},{current_function,{array,set_1,4}},{ancestors,[worker_pool_sup,rabbit_sup,<0.262.0>]},{message_queue_len,0},{links,[<0.276.0>,<0.336.0>,#Port<0.31170>]},{trap_exit,false},{status,runnable},{heap_size,121536},{stack_size,44},{reductions,122988},{current_stacktrace,[{array,set_1,4,[{file,"array.erl"},{line,590}]},{array,set_1,4,[{file,"array.erl"},{line,592}]},{array,set_1,4,[{file,"array.erl"},{line,592}]},{array,set,3,[{file,"array.erl"},{line,574}]},{rabbit_queue_index,parse_segment_publish_entry,5,[{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,1135}]},{rabbit_queue_index,segment_entries_foldr,3,[{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,1091}]},{lists,foldr,3,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1276}]},{rabbit_queue_index,scan_queue_segments,3,[{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,725}]}]}]
    neighbour: [{pid,<0.336.0>},{registered_name,[]},{initial_call,{gatherer,init,['Argument__1']}},{current_function,{gen_server2,process_next_msg,1}},{ancestors,[<0.332.0>,<0.324.0>,<0.323.0>,rabbit_vhost_sup_sup,rabbit_sup,<0.262.0>]},{message_queue_len,2},{links,[<0.280.0>,<0.332.0>,<0.281.0>,<0.278.0>,<0.279.0>]},{trap_exit,false},{status,runnable},{heap_size,987},{stack_size,8},{reductions,73223},{current_stacktrace,[{gen_server2,process_next_msg,1,[{file,"src/gen_server2.erl"},{line,666}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,247}]}]}]
2018-09-11 09:39:42 =CRASH REPORT====
  crasher:
    initial call: rabbit_msg_store:init/1
    pid: <0.332.0>
    registered_name: []
    exception exit: {{{function_clause,[{rabbit_queue_index,journal_minus_segment1,[{{true,<<172,190,166,92,192,205,125,125,36,223,114,188,53,139,128,108,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,26,151>>,<<>>},no_del,no_ack},{{true,<<89,173,78,227,188,37,119,171,231,189,220,236,244,79,138,177,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,40>>,<<>>},no_del,no_ack}],[{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,1231}]},{rabbit_queue_index,'-journal_minus_segment/3-fun-0-',4,[{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,1208}]},{array,sparse_foldl_3,7,[{file,"array.erl"},{line,1684}]},{array,sparse_foldl_2,9,[{file,"array.erl"},{line,1678}]},{rabbit_queue_index,'-recover_journal/1-fun-0-',1,[{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,915}]},{lists,map,2,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1239}]},{rabbit_queue_index,segment_map,2,[{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,1039}]},{rabbit_queue_index,recover_journal,1,[{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,906}]}]},{gen_server2,call,[<0.336.0>,out,infinity]}},[{gen_server2,init_it,6,[{file,"src/gen_server2.erl"},{line,589}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,247}]}]}
    ancestors: [<0.324.0>,<0.323.0>,rabbit_vhost_sup_sup,rabbit_sup,<0.262.0>]
    message_queue_len: 1
    messages: [{'EXIT',<0.336.0>,{function_clause,[{rabbit_queue_index,journal_minus_segment1,[{{true,<<172,190,166,92,192,205,125,125,36,223,114,188,53,139,128,108,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,26,151>>,<<>>},no_del,no_ack},{{true,<<89,173,78,227,188,37,119,171,231,189,220,236,244,79,138,177,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,40>>,<<>>},no_del,no_ack}],[{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,1231}]},{rabbit_queue_index,'-journal_minus_segment/3-fun-0-',4,[{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,1208}]},{array,sparse_foldl_3,7,[{file,"array.erl"},{line,1684}]},{array,sparse_foldl_2,9,[{file,"array.erl"},{line,1678}]},{rabbit_queue_index,'-recover_journal/1-fun-0-',1,[{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,915}]},{lists,map,2,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1239}]},{rabbit_queue_index,segment_map,2,[{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,1039}]},{rabbit_queue_index,recover_journal,1,[{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,906}]}]}}]
    links: [<0.335.0>,<0.324.0>]
    dictionary: []
    trap_exit: true
    status: running
    heap_size: 2586
    stack_size: 27
    reductions: 57377
  neighbours:
    neighbour: [{pid,<0.335.0>},{registered_name,[]},{initial_call,{rabbit_msg_store_gc,init,['Argument__1']}},{current_function,{gen_server2,process_next_msg,1}},{ancestors,[<0.332.0>,<0.324.0>,<0.323.0>,rabbit_vhost_sup_sup,rabbit_sup,<0.262.0>]},{message_queue_len,0},{links,[<0.332.0>]},{trap_exit,false},{status,waiting},{heap_size,987},{stack_size,8},{reductions,174},{current_stacktrace,[{gen_server2,process_next_msg,1,[{file,"src/gen_server2.erl"},{line,666}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,247}]}]}]
2018-09-11 09:39:42 =SUPERVISOR REPORT====
     Supervisor: {local,worker_pool_sup}
     Context:    child_terminated
     Reason:     {function_clause,[{rabbit_queue_index,journal_minus_segment1,[{{true,<<172,190,166,92,192,205,125,125,36,223,114,188,53,139,128,108,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,26,151>>,<<>>},no_del,no_ack},{{true,<<89,173,78,227,188,37,119,171,231,189,220,236,244,79,138,177,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,40>>,<<>>},no_del,no_ack}],[{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,1231}]},{rabbit_queue_index,'-journal_minus_segment/3-fun-0-',4,[{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,1208}]},{array,sparse_foldl_3,7,[{file,"array.erl"},{line,1684}]},{array,sparse_foldl_2,9,[{file,"array.erl"},{line,1678}]},{rabbit_queue_index,'-recover_journal/1-fun-0-',1,[{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,915}]},{lists,map,2,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1239}]},{rabbit_queue_index,segment_map,2,[{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,1039}]},{rabbit_queue_index,recover_journal,1,[{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,906}]}]}
     Offender:   [{pid,<0.281.0>},{id,4},{mfargs,{worker_pool_worker,start_link,[worker_pool]}},{restart_type,transient},{shutdown,4294967295},{child_type,worker}]

2018-09-11 09:39:42 =CRASH REPORT====
  crasher:
initial call: rabbit_vhost_process:init/1
pid: <0.325.0>
registered_name: []
exception exit: {{error,{{{function_clause,[{rabbit_queue_index,journal_minus_segment1,[{{true,<<172,190,166,92,192,205,125,125,36,223,114,188,53,139,128,108,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,26,151>>,<<>>},no_del,no_ack},{{true,<<89,173,78,227,188,37,119,171,231,189,220,236,244,79,138,177,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,40>>,<<>>},no_del,no_ack}],[{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,1231}]},{rabbit_queue_index,'-journal_minus_segment/3-fun-0-',4,[{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,1208}]},{array,sparse_foldl_3,7,[{file,"array.erl"},{line,1684}]},{array,sparse_foldl_2,9,[{file,"array.erl"},{line,1678}]},{rabbit_queue_index,'-recover_journal/1-fun-0-',1,[{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,915}]},{lists,map,2,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1239}]},{rabbit_queue_index,segment_map,2,[{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,1039}]},{rabbit_queue_index,recover_journal,1,[{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,906}]}]},{gen_server2,call,[<0.336.0>,out,infinity]}},{child,undefined,msg_store_persistent,{rabbit_msg_store,start_link,[msg_store_persistent,"c:/Users/dfpsb/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/db/RABBIT~1/msg_stores/vhosts/628WB79CIFDYO9LJI6DKMI09L",[],{#Fun<rabbit_queue_index.2.122888644>,{start,[{resource,<<"/">>,queue,<<"DF-9ID59RK-WS.InterchangeFragtbrevEnvelope.TurPlan">>},{resource,<<"/">>,queue,<<"Test1.InterchangeFragtbrevEnvelope.RET">>},{resource,<<"/">>,queue,<<"Test2.DfLoggingEvent.Debug">>},{resource,<<"/">>,queue,<<"DF-9ID59RK-WS.InterchangeTurEnvelope.DFMobil">>},{resource,<<"/">>,queue,<<"Paw.DfLoggingEvent.Debug">>},{resource,<<"/">>,queue,<<"DevUnitTest.TruckLoadingEnvelope.UnitTest">>},{resource,<<"/">>,queue,<<"Test1.InterchangeFragtbrevEnvelope.RET_error">>},{resource,<<"/">>,queue,<<"Paw.InterchangeFragtbrevEnvelope.TurPlan">>},{resource,<<"/">>,queue,<<"DevUnitTest.TestMsg.UnitTest_error">>},{resource,<<"/">>,queue,<<"DevUnitTest.TestMsg.UnitTest">>},{resource,<<"/">>,queue,<<"Paw.InterchangeTurEnvelope.DFMobil">>},{resource,<<"/">>,queue,<<"Test2.InterchangeFragtbrevEnvelope.TurPlan">>},{resource,<<"/">>,queue,<<"Paw.InterchangeFragtbrevEnvelope.TurPlan_error">>},{resource,<<"/">>,queue,<<"Paw.TruckLoadingEnvelope.TurPlan">>},{resource,<<"/">>,queue,<<"Test2.InterchangeFragtbrevEnvelope.TurPlan_error">>},{resource,<<"/">>,queue,<<"Test2.TruckLoadingEnvelope.TurPlan">>},{resource,<<"/">>,queue,<<"Paw.DfLoggingEvent.Warning">>},{resource,<<"/">>,queue,<<"DF-9ID59RK-WS.InterchangeFragtbrevEnvelope.RET">>},{resource,<<"/">>,queue,<<"Test2.InterchangeTurEnvelope.DFMobil">>},{resource,<<"/">>,queue,<<"Test2.DfLoggingEvent.Warning">>}]}}]},transient,30000,worker,[rabbit_msg_store]}}},[{gen_server2,init_it,6,[{file,"src/gen_server2.erl"},{line,581}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,247}]}]}
ancestors: [<0.323.0>,rabbit_vhost_sup_sup,rabbit_sup,<0.262.0>]
message_queue_len: 0
messages: []
links: [<0.323.0>]
dictionary: []
trap_exit: true
status: running
heap_size: 10958
stack_size: 27
reductions: 63314
  neighbours:
2018-09-11 09:39:42 =SUPERVISOR REPORT====
 Supervisor: {<0.323.0>,rabbit_vhost_sup_wrapper}
 Context:    start_error
 Reason:     {error,{{{function_clause,[{rabbit_queue_index,journal_minus_segment1,[{{true,<<172,190,166,92,192,205,125,125,36,223,114,188,53,139,128,108,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,26,151>>,<<>>},no_del,no_ack},{{true,<<89,173,78,227,188,37,119,171,231,189,220,236,244,79,138,177,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,40>>,<<>>},no_del,no_ack}],[{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,1231}]},{rabbit_queue_index,'-journal_minus_segment/3-fun-0-',4,[{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,1208}]},{array,sparse_foldl_3,7,[{file,"array.erl"},{line,1684}]},{array,sparse_foldl_2,9,[{file,"array.erl"},{line,1678}]},{rabbit_queue_index,'-recover_journal/1-fun-0-',1,[{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,915}]},{lists,map,2,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1239}]},{rabbit_queue_index,segment_map,2,[{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,1039}]},{rabbit_queue_index,recover_journal,1,[{file,"src/rabbit_queue_index.erl"},{line,906}]}]},{gen_server2,call,[<0.336.0>,out,infinity]}},{child,undefined,msg_store_persistent,{rabbit_msg_store,start_link,[msg_store_persistent,"c:/Users/dfpsb/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/db/RABBIT~1/msg_stores/vhosts/628WB79CIFDYO9LJI6DKMI09L",[],{#Fun<rabbit_queue_index.2.122888644>,{start,[{resource,<<"/">>,queue,<<"DF-9ID59RK-WS.InterchangeFragtbrevEnvelope.TurPlan">>},{resource,<<"/">>,queue,<<"Test1.InterchangeFragtbrevEnvelope.RET">>},{resource,<<"/">>,queue,<<"Test2.DfLoggingEvent.Debug">>},{resource,<<"/">>,queue,<<"DF-9ID59RK-WS.InterchangeTurEnvelope.DFMobil">>},{resource,<<"/">>,queue,<<"Paw.DfLoggingEvent.Debug">>},{resource,<<"/">>,queue,<<"DevUnitTest.TruckLoadingEnvelope.UnitTest">>},{resource,<<"/">>,queue,<<"Test1.InterchangeFragtbrevEnvelope.RET_error">>},{resource,<<"/">>,queue,<<"Paw.InterchangeFragtbrevEnvelope.TurPlan">>},{resource,<<"/">>,queue,<<"DevUnitTest.TestMsg.UnitTest_error">>},{resource,<<"/">>,queue,<<"DevUnitTest.TestMsg.UnitTest">>},{resource,<<"/">>,queue,<<"Paw.InterchangeTurEnvelope.DFMobil">>},{resource,<<"/">>,queue,<<"Test2.InterchangeFragtbrevEnvelope.TurPlan">>},{resource,<<"/">>,queue,<<"Paw.InterchangeFragtbrevEnvelope.TurPlan_error">>},{resource,<<"/">>,queue,<<"Paw.TruckLoadingEnvelope.TurPlan">>},{resource,<<"/">>,queue,<<"Test2.InterchangeFragtbrevEnvelope.TurPlan_error">>},{resource,<<"/">>,queue,<<"Test2.TruckLoadingEnvelope.TurPlan">>},{resource,<<"/">>,queue,<<"Paw.DfLoggingEvent.Warning">>},{resource,<<"/">>,queue,<<"DF-9ID59RK-WS.InterchangeFragtbrevEnvelope.RET">>},{resource,<<"/">>,queue,<<"Test2.InterchangeTurEnvelope.DFMobil">>},{resource,<<"/">>,queue,<<"Test2.DfLoggingEvent.Warning">>}]}}]},transient,30000,worker,[rabbit_msg_store]}}}
 Offender:   [{pid,undefined},{id,rabbit_vhost_process},{mfargs,{rabbit_vhost_process,start_link,[<<"/">>]}},{restart_type,permanent},{shutdown,30000},{child_type,worker}]
```

Comment: I suggest doing a search on the keyword `journal_minus_segment1` - you'll find relevant information. In addition, providing information like RabbitMQ and Erlang version is required to narrow issues down. [This document](https://github.com/rabbitmq/support-tools/blob/master/docs/Reporting_RabbitMQ_Issues.md) has suggestions for what information should be provided. Finally, the [`rabbitmq-users`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users) mailing list is the best place to get help as the core team members monitor it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured out what was going on. Someone on my team (me) was creating an unprecedented amount of connections to RabbitMQ. For each connection a file handler is created to one or more files, not sure which. The OS (Windows in my case) has a file handler limit, not sure what the limit is, but when reached, an error is thrown. This corrupted the virtual host (/) and I had to delete it and create it again. Good thing this wasn't production, because then all the messages would've been gone.

**Edit (June 2020):**

There might be a fix for this so it can't happen again. A virtual host can be limited in how many connections they allow. This way Windows won't faulter on the many file handles. Look in the management portal -> Admin -> Limits, set max-connections to a number you think it plausible for your setup.

[image: max-connections]

Comment: you can delete contains of /var/lib/rabbitmq/.mnesia and restart rabbit.

Comment: Thanks @JamesM this solved my problem, however it also deleted my users, so I had to re-create them, and also re-created guest (which is a vulnerability)!

Answer (score 1):

For me, I was trying to install management plugin (rabbitmqadmin) and it failed in 
rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange. So I downloaded rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange from JFrog Bintray and updated my plugins folder, stopped and started rabbitmq service. This action, courrupted the database.

To fix it,

1. Stop Rabbitmq service
2. I went to %APPDATA%\RabbitMQ\db and cleared the data in transient msg_stores & queues folders. e.g. C:\Users\bharath\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ\db\rabbit@js-mnesia\msg_stores\vhosts\6ZOILVXV632BBEWZY4TBABTPP\msg_store_transient
3. Removed the rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange from rabbit@js-plugins-expand folder
4. Removed the data in transient msg_store & queues from RABBIT~1-upgrade-backup folder
5. Went one folder back and removed the plugin name rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange, from enabled_plugins file
6. Start the rabbitmq service

It worked!!!

Note: Only try this if data is not important, as it will get cleared or you can restore it from backup.

Comment: Variant of this worked for me - I purged `rabbit@<machineName>-mnesia` from the `db` folder. Possibly was caused by a full disk and it didn't recover after purging. I didn't care about data loss on my dev machine

Answer (score 1):

In my case, there was a problem with corrupted data on a disk. What I did:

1. Logged in to the host reporting issue
2. Stopped the RabbitMQ application and resetting it

   ```
   sudo rabbitmqctl start_app
   sudo rabbitmqctl reset
   ```
3. Removed directory `/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/{vhost_name}`
4. Removed faulty node from the cluster by logging into one of the existing nodes in the RabbitMQ cluster and running the given command:

   ```
   sudo rabbitmqctl forget_cluster_node {vhost_name}@{faulty_node_name}
   ```
5. On the faulty node, re-join the cluster

   ```
   sudo rabbitmqctl join_cluster {vhost_name}@{any_working_cluster_node}
   ```
6. Enable the RabbitMQ app

   ```
   sudo rabbitmqctl start_app
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I opted to recreate the vhost which resolved the issue for me.

Clearing the data in transient msg_stores & queues didn't work for me in my scenario. Since data loss wasn't an issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

use `sudo` to run rabbitmq

```
sudo rabbitmqctl stop

sudo rabbitmq-server -detached
```